# SQL UNION ALL for a single result

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, Example student table and student_History table. 
Both the student and student_Hostory tables contain the same number of columns. If a student is in the History table they wont be in the Student table.(One index number A0001 can only be in one table either student or student_history)

If I want to get a student details from the index number, I have to do the 'union all' to both tables and find the user.

Is there a easy way to get this done, other than the UNION ALL. since the result set only contain one row either in student or student_history table.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: Union all is an easy way that doesn't take a lot of resources, what the problem here?

Comment: Instead of checking in both tables I want to stop the search if the result is found in the first table. is it possible ?

Comment: Listen, even if both table are very big, and by the name of you tables I assume they are not, it won't hurt you performance in anyway.

Comment: Sorry this is just an example I took. my original tables are bit big and the select of each  contains an inner join  to a other table to get data.

Comment: SELECT  MA.AM_ANAME , MA.AM_AVERSION , MP.RP_NAME FROM MONO_SUBS MA INNER JOIN MONO_PLANS MP ON MA.RP_ID =MP.RP_ID WHERE MA.SUB_ID = 'A-861' limit 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT  MA.AM_ANAME , MA.AM_AVERSION , MP.RP_NAME FROM MONO_SUBS_HISTORY MA INNER JOIN MONO_PLANS MP ON MA.RP_ID =MP.RP_ID WHERE MA.SUB_ID = 'A-861' limit 1 ;

Comment: You can try the other way around, starting from MONO_SUBS table and doing two outer joins on MA and MA_HISTORY. But then you get more columns, 3 from MA and 3 from MA_HISTORY. Of course you can use a CASE statement to merge on the fly the columns. Let me know if the solution could be feasible for you...

Comment: Outer Join dose not work in mysql right ?